# How to install Android on BQ Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, tablet, aquaris, m10

I've been amongst the first users of BQ's Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition tablet and I'd been waiting for a Ubuntu tablet for 4+ years.
Now after playing around a lot my final rating for this device + OS is not a positive one. Amongst the most annoying weak points for me are:

- no multi user ability
- not a real Ubuntu Linux inside but still a tuned Android only, hence missing a lot of Linux tools, e.g. [openSSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793470/how-to-install-openssh-server-on-bq-aquaris-m10-ubuntu-tablet)
- Bluetooth does not usefully work
- really horrible and sloppy touch experience even after OS update
- almost useless app landscape: To fill the app store, an estimated 99% off all 'apps' are nothing but (mobile) websites in headless browsers from solo developers who call their apps a test or 'beta'
- Even standard tablet features such as serving as a music player with the Ubuntu native player is a farce...

I apologize for my rant and happily accept any down ratings for being off-topic. But hopefully, I'll get eventually a useful device with a modern state-of-the-art operation system:

Now, to my regret but to keep myself from getting even more grey hairs:

How can I completely remove Ubuntu from the M10 tablet and replace it with a fresh Android installation?

Comment: The rant is in fact quite interesting. But the actual question I think it should be better asked on the Android Enthusiasts SE website. I guess that those guys there should know how to wipe out any other OS in order to install Android on their devices. So, better ask for their guidance. Here, on AskUbuntu, you're on the verge of the Grand Off-Topic Land. ;-)

Comment: @CristianaNicolae you could be right . Being an Ubuntu supporter for many years now, I didn't even know nor think about the Android Enthusiasts SE channel. But, yeah - why should Ubuntu folks help me getting rid of the OS on tablet.. :)

Comment: In case you get stuck in the StackExchange "maze", here is the link for Android Enthusiasts SE website: https://android.stackexchange.com/ @Bunjip

Comment: Cheers! I'll keep my question still a bit running here on askubuntu just to see what experience others may have with the tablet...

Comment: I think that you should keep your post here too. It's true, your question is a bit... "crossover", and a more severe moderator, could close it. But, on the other hand, the experience you have with that kind of tablet, can be useful for others. Most of the tablets in the market run Android. You have one which runs Ubuntu. You are one of the pioneers. Your feedback on this tablet can encourage others to do the same. And your feedback, other people's feedback, can, in the end, improve Ubuntu, can help it conquer the mobile world. @Bunjip

Comment: Maybe these links will help you. They are dedicated forums. Here are the ones for the Ubuntu Edition: http://www.mibqyyo.com/comunidad/categories/aquaris-m10-fhd-ubuntu-edition-en , and http://www.mibqyyo.com/comunidad/categories/aquaris-m10-hd-ubuntu-edition-en. @Bunjip

Comment: @CristianaNicolae - Yeah, I'd be more than happy if Ubuntu would eventually become a serious opponent to the technology monopolists who rule the consumer market in terms of devices and software by using their customers data as the actual product.
Therefore, I'm not glad about my idea to replace Ubuntu on my BQ M10. However, at current stage, this device-OS-combination is too far away from production ready usage on a consumer market.
If I could support Ubuntu to create an open source landscape that can truly compete with the walled gardens of ApplGooglMicrosftAmazn I would participate

Comment: I think that since Ubuntu is using stackexchange as the official support forum (whether or not it is suitable) this should be the place to ask. Especially as the product you (and I) bought (and, I hope contributed some money to Canonical / Ubuntu) has so many problems.

Comment: @Joe - Well, that's a good point. Anyway, your argument is quite convincing. I have to mention something though: the official support forum for Ubuntu is, in fact, UbuntuForums, while AskUbuntu has a total different format - it is a Q&A type of website and has to follow a certain set of rules (which apply to all the StackExchange websites). This rigour makes AskUbuntu much more "appealing" than UbuntuForums, because the information is more accessible, and, perhaps, more accurate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This very question was asked and answered on the BQ support forum:

http://www.mibqyyo.com/comunidad/discussion/75471/is-there-any-guidance-i-can-replace-the-ubuntu-with-android-for-m10-fhd/

First you need to download the appropriate firmware:

FHD: http://www.mibqyyo.com/en-download/categorias/aquaris-m10-fhd/

HD: http://www.mibqyyo.com/en-download/categorias/aquaris-m10-hd/

Then, you can find instructions for installing Android here:

http://www.mibqyyo.com/en-articles/2015/09/16/ubuntu-android-installation-process-for-bq-aquaris-e4-5-and-e5/

BQ suggests you need the updated flash tool: https://storage.googleapis.com/otas/2015/Tablets/Freezer%20FHD/Ubuntu/SP_Flash_Tool_exe_Linux_v5.1612.00.100.zip

Note that these instructions are not specifically for M10, but they are the instructions suggested by BQ tech support on the BQ support forum linked to at the top of this answer. Several users there report success using this method.

**Discaimer**: On the same forum, BQ support say you will not void your warranty by following the instructions, but you should check this yourself if you are worried about such things. Finally, I have not tried it myself and thus cannot vouch for the method's effectiveness.

Comment: I think that all the points raised are all very valid and I personally encourage posts/queztions like this. The more honest answers we can get the better (hopefully) the overall OS will be. There is no point Ubuntu Touch surrounding itself in 'Yes man', when as soon as it goes out to the market, it falls down. I have raised a few issues with the OS and I feel that they are being looked into, be it slowly. I have three of the tablets and do like them. Hopefully more releases will bring greater functionality. I would encourage you to long anything in Launchpad though. To help drive it forward.

Comment: I tried to bend the ubuntu touch tablet to my workflow, and get some key mobile programs (for cool things, not staring to the screen like retarded) working, and could not do that in last 4 months: The new mobile version of the app requires Qt5.6, and is impossible to compile for touch, desktop version in convergence crashes... Also important piece like gps (and external powerful gps) does not work. So I moved to android, thanks to this instructions. I got ready for my work in one evening, got that mobile app installed... However now I see how android is horrible... Still no perfect mobile os..

Comment: How do I use this on newer Ubuntu's? 'Cause it keeps searching for USB but doesn't find any device even though my M10 FHD is connected properly.

Comment: I realize this answer is several years old, but the links seem to point at a Spanish language forum posts which no longer exist. does anyone know how to access 
English language instructionss regarding how to install Android on one of these devices?